# Is it integration by parts?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help understanding following integration equalities.
Let $f \in C_{c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ then

\begin{align*}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \cos(t |y|) \sin(t |y|) f \  dy &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n}} \sin(2t |y|) f dy  & \text{by additon Theorem}\\
& = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{\infty}  \sin(2t r) \int_{\partial B(0,r)} f \  dS dr
& \text{since $f$ is compactly supported?}\\
&= -\frac{1}{4t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{d r} (\cos(2t r)) \int_{\partial B(0,r)} f \  dS dr &\text{derivative of cos is sin}\\
& =  \frac{1}{4t} \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos(2t r)  \frac{d}{d r} \Big(\int_{\partial B(0,r)} f \ dS \Big ) dr &\text{integration by parts ???}
\end{align*}
If yes shouldn't be there sine instead of cosine?

Comment: $-\int_0^{\infty}\alpha’(r)\beta(r)\,dr=\int_0^{\infty}\alpha(r)\beta’(r)\,dr$ if $\beta(0)=0$ and $\beta$ is compactly supported. Apply this with $\alpha(r)=\cos(2tr)$ and $\beta(r)=\int_{\partial B(0,r)}f\,dS$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Thank you. Why the term $\alpha(r) \beta(r)|^\infty_{r=0}$ vanishes? 
Isn't it indeterminate, because $\lim_{r \to \infty}\alpha(r) \beta(r)$ oscilates?

Comment: Also here $f$ is compactly supported, I don't see why $\beta$ also is.

Comment: Okay I can see now why $\beta$ is compactly supported, we integrate over slices of the support. So $\beta(\infty) = 0 $Thank you!!!